# How to show cursor first line on textbox

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I want to show cursor first line of textbox if I press enter key. But always my cursor show in second line. please anyone can help me solving this problem. thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#txt_message').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 ){
    $('#txt_message').val("");
            }
})
});
</script>
    </head>
        <body>
 <textarea  id='txt_message'></textarea>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works for me : http://jsfiddle.net/fgBU4/ (the cursor in the first line)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/VQh9t/ yes work fine for me. see your textarea padding.please make it 0

Comment: @Osiris  he is talking about what happens after the enter key press

Comment: If I press enter then cursor show on second line. first time it show first line. I check all of your link. here is same problem. Thanks for yours response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#txt_message').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 ){
    e.preventDefault();//use this to prevent default behavior 
    $('#txt_message').val("");
   }
```

[demo js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52QfW/)